# react native) how to pass a state to another file?

Tags: react-native

I ask you a question because I have a problem while developing an application with React Native.

I want to enter information required for 'state' generated by 'Add.js' at several stages.

Finally, the information entered at each step is applied to the 'state' to show in the file called 'info.js'.

I am writing a program with the following courses.

1. Create 'state' in 'Add.js', enter 'name, dosage'
2. Enter 'bool type' in 'cycle, special' in 'Reminder.js'
3. ...other input steps...
4. Publish 'state' information entered in 'info.js'

What I'm curious about is the process of proceeding from level 1 to level 2.

I'd like to hand over the 'state' to 'Reminder.js', including the information of 'name, destination' entered in 'Add.js. And I would like to enter other information in 'Reminder.js'.
How should I modify this code?

Add.js

```js
export default class Add extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: "",
            dosage: 0,
            Cycle: false,
            Specific: false,
        }
    }
    static propTypes = {
        name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        dosage: PropTypes.number.isRequired,      
    }
    render() {
        const {name, dosage}=this.state
        return (
            <View>
                <Title>Add Medication</Title>
                <SubTitle>Step 1. Medication Information</SubTitle>
                <Descript>1. What is the name of the medication?</Descript>
                <TextBox
                    placeholder="Name"
                    style={{ marginBottom: 30 }}
                    onChangeText={(name)=>this.setState({name})}
                    value={this.state.name}
                />
                <Descript>2. What is the dosage?(Optional)</Descript>
                <TextBox
                    placeholder="e.g. 2"
                    onChangeText={(dosage)=>this.setState({dosage})}
                    value={this.state.dosage}
                />
                <Condition>Should be numeric</Condition>
                <Button title="Next" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Reminder")} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Add.js ==(state)==> Reminder.js

Reminder.js

```js
export default ({navigation}) => (
    <View>
        <Title>Add Medication</Title>
        <SubTitle>Step 2. Step Reminder</SubTitle>
        <Descript>How do you want to set the reminder?</Descript>
        <Button onPress={()=> navigation.navigate("Specific")}>
            <ButtonText>Set specific time</ButtonText>
        </Button>
        <Button onPress={()=> navigation.navigate("Cycle")}>
            <ButtonText>Set cycle</ButtonText>
        </Button>
    </View>
);
```

Comment: If you want to use stored information for multiple files/places... try it using Redux instead of the state. check this link for better understanding https://blog.logrocket.com/why-use-redux-reasons-with-clear-examples-d21bffd5835/

Comment: thank you for your advice! this is what I  was looking for :)